# Separating validators for put and patch Spring data rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

With Spring Data Rest, Both `put` and `patch` requests will be registered in `beforeSave` so they will be using the same validator.

```
@Override
protected void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener v) {
  v.addValidator("beforeSave", new BeforeSaveValidator());
}
```

Is there any way to register different validators for `put` and `patch` requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible. Write a custom controller to handle PUT and PATCH.

Remember Spring Data REST is not a sliver bullet to handle all scenarios. When it doesn't fullful your requirement, just write custom controller as a supplement.

Comment: Thank you sir. I’m going to override the default ones, just curious if there’s any other way.